# Convert a simple WinForms app to WPF, specifically MVVM

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, mvvm

**Background:** A while back I created a simple VB.NET WinForms app at work that consists of one form and one module. The app simply reads from and makes updates to an Oracle database.

Recently I was asked if I could learn C# WPF and MVVM when creating apps going forward. I figured this app was simple enough to try to convert so that I can learn from it for when I take on a more challenging project. And I have to admit that I am having a very difficult time. I figured that if I could just get the MVVM part set up correctly in at least one part of the app (the connecting/reading/verifying of an employee ID on the database), that experience would enable me to do the rest on my own. I don't have much experience with C# and I don't know if I got the Model and ViewModel correct here or if they need to be reversed.

---

**Goal:** What I want to do here is type the employee ID in the textbox and click the button. If the employee ID exists, do something. If not, then display a message box.

I started by creating three folders in the IDE:  `Model`, `View` and `ViewModel`. I then created `Model.cs`, `MainWindow.xaml` and `ViewModel.cs`.

I've made enough progress to make the public class `Verify` work. But, I don't know if I've done it correctly at all and clearly the behavior I want isn't happening.

**Model.cs**

```
namespace Wpf_BrazeKiosk.Model
{
    public class Model
    {

    }

    public class Verify
    {
        public const string ConnectionStringToORACLE = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=MPCS;User ID=secret;Password=secret;";
        public OleDbDataReader rowread;
        public OleDbDataReader Emp_verify(string emp)
        {
            var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "select employee_id from mpcs.employee where employee_id = ?";
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("employee_id", emp);
            rowread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return rowread;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Wpf_BrazeKiosk.ViewModel
{        
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private string _EmpID;
        public string EmpID
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_EmpID == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _EmpID = value;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_BrazeKiosk.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_BrazeKiosk"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="837" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Height="23" Margin="444,423,416,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Remove" Margin="369,612,351,0" Width="260" Height="124" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: and what is the question? do you expect someone to write remaining 90-95% part for you?

Comment: [Better User and Developer Experiences – From Windows Forms to WPF with MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) by Reed Copsey, Jr.

Comment: WPF is UI framework, MVVM is pattern/method to separate code in different "modules" perfectly supported by powerfull data-binding of WPF. You can re-design your Winform application to use MVVM (Winform support data-binding too, not so powerful as WPF, but enough for your application). Then you can move to WPF where you will need only change UI code and reuse same viewmodels/models of Winforms application

Comment: @ASh No I don't expect anyone to write 95%.  I didn't know 95% was left.  I'm not going to rewrite my entire question from above down here.

Comment: Above is everything I got done so far to just make the `public class Verify` work but I don't know if I've done it correctly at all and clearly it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to stop, get a book on the subject, and read it.  Go to Amazon, search for wpf mvvm, rank by review, and buy the top one. It'll take you a day, but you'll be 1000% better off. You might even learn that your view model needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for bindings to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `ICommand` property to the view model. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about commands and what they are used for: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/. There is a lot more information about MVVM and commands available online if you search for it.

Once you have done this you simply bind the `Command` property of the `Button` to the `ICommand` property of the view model and the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to your `EmpID` property:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding EmpID}"/>
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Remove" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
```

...and implement your logic in the `Execute` method of the command, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        YourCommandProperty = new DelegateCommand(Check);
    }
    private string _EmpID;
    public string EmpID
    {
        get
        {
            return _EmpID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_EmpID == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _EmpID = value;
        }
    }

    public ICommand YourCommandProperty { get; }

    private void Check(object o)
    {
        //look up EmpId here...
        MessageBox.Show("...");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of your `ViewModel` class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```